# Merge string and variable to a variable with SASS

Tags: variables, sass

I want to merge a variable and a string to a new variable, like the following:

```
$product_bodyclass_list: class1 class2 class3 class4;

$product_class1_color: #C00;
$product_class2_color: #00C;
$product_class3_color: #0C0;
$product_class4_color: #000;

@each $bodyclass in $product_bodyclass_list {
    .page-#{$bodyclass} {
        a {
            color: $product_#{$bodyclass}_color; // This is wrong
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, you can't have dynamic variables.

From the [docs](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_):

> You can also use SassScript variables in selectors and property names using #{} interpolation

You can accomplish the same effect using two lists and the `nth()` function.

```
$products: class1, class2, class3, class4;    
$product_colors: #C00, #00C, #0C0, #000;

$i: 1;
@each $class in $products {
    .page-#{$class} {
        a {
            color: nth($product_colors, $i)
        }
    }
  $i: $i + 1;
}
```

Also, it might be cleaner to use the `@for` directive:

```
@for $i from 1 through length($products) {
    .page-#{nth($products, $i)} {
        a {
            color: nth($product_colors, $i)
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, if you want to define the variables explicitly so you can use them elsewhere, make a list of variables:

```
$product_class1_color: #C00;
$product_class2_color: #00C;
$product_class3_color: #0C0;
$product_class4_color: #000;

$product_colors: $product_class1_color, $product_class2_color, $product_class3_color, $product_class4_color;
```

Comment: That works! Super! Thnx!

Comment: You could also make the first example cleaner by going `color: nth($product-colors, index($products, $class))`

Comment: @bookcasey thanks for this. I used your second option

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE: [Sass maps](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#maps) make this answer pretty much obsolete.**

Another option is to use one list, with two elements each, and use it as a hashmap.

```sass
$products: class1 #C00, class2 #00C, class3 #0C0, class4 #000;

@each $kvp in $products { // kvp stands for 'key-value pair'
    .page-#{nth($kvp, 1)} {
        a {
            color: nth($kvp, 2);
        }
    }
}
```

I like to make simple functions to make the meaning of my code clearer. I'd probably do something more like:

```sass
@function kvp-key($kvp) {
    @return nth($kvp, 1);
}

@function kvp-value($kvp) {
    @if length($kvp) == 2 {
        @return nth($kvp, 2);
    } @else {
        @warn "argument was not a key-value pair";
        @return null;
    }
}
```

And then I'd reimplement the loop like this:

```sass
@each $kvp in $products { // kvp stands for 'key-value pair'
    .page-#{kvp-key($kvp)} {
        a {
            color: kvp-value($kvp);
        }
    }
}
```

We haven't saved any lines, but we've made the intent of the loop a bit clearer.