# SASS: overwrite var when beneath a special body class

Tags: variables, sass

perhaps I got a failure in my design but my SASS is defined like this:

```
$Akzent: #6d998e; // green

// ........
a {
 color: $Akzent;
}

.section .foo {
  background-color: $Akzent;
}
// ... many more definitions that go back on $Akzent
```

now I got a webpage that needs $Akzent to have another color. I'm not able to overwrite the color val of $Akzent when beneath another body class.

I tried something like this:

```
$Akzent: #6d998e; // default akzent (green)

body.page-aktzent-2 {
  $Akzent: #ff9900; // override akzent with orange
}

a {
 color: $Akzent:
}
// ........ more sass code
```

but this won't work.

I don't want to redefine alle previous definitions which use $Akzent to now use another var.

How do I manage to solve my problem without rewriting everything?

Mixings also seem not to bring me any solution.

Tryed this: [Set a variable in Sass depending on the selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112238/set-a-variable-in-sass-depending-on-the-selector) but this is not suitable for my current sass code.

Comment: Always keep in mind that your SASS code isn't aware of the current page, so it has to compile to a CSS file which defines the color of an `a` and other definitions, wrapped by all possible body classes. The SASS machnismns for creating such CSS code are mixins, loops, and what else is described in the answers of the linked question. What you tried doesn't result in an additional wrapper around all of your other definitions, but instead overrides the variable in the given scope.

Comment: If you don't want to touch your existing code, you could try to create a new SCSS file with the `body.page-akzent-2` wrapper, set the color like you did in your try, and import the file with the definitions for `a` and so on in this wrapper (hope this works somehow in SASS, at least it does in LESS).

Comment: You will not be able to achieve it the way you are trying. Because of variables scope, you can't change the variable value outside its scope, so, no matter what, `$Akzent` will always have the default color in the `a`. Remember that `scss` is a css processor, so the values won't change runtime: you need to define your rules in your css. To achieve your exampe, you will need a base `a` defined, plus a `body.page-akzent-2 a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<div class="block orange"></div>
<div class="block red"></div>

$Akzent: #6d998e !default;

.block {
  min-height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.orange {
  $Akzent: orange;
  background-color: $Akzent;
}

.red {
  $Akzent: red;
  background-color: $Akzent;
}
```

working codepen link [here](https://codepen.io/arpanpatel/pen/XqxJZx)

Comment: this does not help me in any way - I need a complete different color, not only a lighter version of my given default accent - the default color is green, the subpage needs orange (#ff9900) as $Akzent

Comment: perhaps I don't get it - but I don't think this will help - this will force me to have everything (every class definition for elements on the page) twice in the SASS, for EVERY color accent a sub page may have.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I may understand the approach you are going for. I did something similar for having another theme option for a page and simply would add a class to the body as well.

In your case, your second "theme" would have the class `page-akzent-2` added to the `body`.

Best way I find is to add another variable for you new color and overwrite your original color everywhere needed with nesting:

```
$akzent:   #6d998e; // default akzent (green)
$akzent-2: #ff9900; // second akzent (orange)

a {
    color: $akzent:

    body.page-akzent-2 & {
        color: $akzent-2; // override akzent with orange
    }
}
// ........ more sass code
```

Comment: Hope that helps you!

Comment: gonna check how far this will bring me, thanks! I guess my problem is that I forgot that sass is NOT compiled at runtime of the page but once before - so of course no scripting and checking of the current class set is possible... I obviously just broke the design of sass :/

Comment: well if it works for you just dont forget to mark this as the approved answer :) I once thought the way your were trying to go about it would be a neat, but it's just not how it happens to work.