# How can i change sass variable values when parent html-tag is `nav`?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

Variables:

```
     $inverse-icon-button-background: #ddd !default;
     $inverse-icon-button-color: $bbb !default;
     $inverse-icon-button-hover-background: $ccc !default;
     $inverse-icon-button-hover-color: #000 !default;
```

I'd like to change variable values when parent tag is `nav`, like this:

```
nav > {
     $inverse-icon-button-background: #fff !default;
     $inverse-icon-button-color: $blue !default;
     $inverse-icon-button-hover-background: $green !default;
     $inverse-icon-button-hover-color: #fff !default;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set a variable in Sass depending on the selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18112238/set-a-variable-in-sass-depending-on-the-selector)

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
nav {
     inverse-icon-button-background: #fff !default;
     inverse-icon-button-color: $blue !default;
     inverse-icon-button-hover-background: $green !default;
     inverse-icon-button-hover-color: #fff !default;
}
```